# v-file-input .click() is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I was trying to programmatically trigger .click() event of v-file-input because it has on the documentation at Vuetify.

[image: Vuetify v-file-input events docs]

but it shows an error `this.$refs.imagePicker.click is not a function`
am I missing something here?

[image: codepen reproduction error]

Code Reproduction: https://codepen.io/kforr24/pen/ZEQweLP

I'm trying to upload an image using a certain button. Like that certain button would trigger a click event on the v-file-input.

Comment: 'click' is the name of the event `$emit`ted by Vuetify, not the internal method name used to trigger that emit.

If you provided more info about what you're trying to do with the programmatic trigger, you could get more help trying to solve the problem.

Comment: So, what would be the work around, same as the way as clicking an html <input> tag using a certain button?

Comment: I'm not sure if the function name is `onclick`. Can you try that?

Comment: @MaxPeng onClick is triggered when you click the input, not clicking/activating it.

Comment: I think you want `this.$refs.image.$el.click()`

Comment: You can do `this.$refs.image.$refs.input.click()`.

Answer (score 33):

[@User28's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63030356/#comment111461866_63030356) (one of the comments below the question) works:

`this.$refs.image.$refs.input.click()`

Comment: Working solution for vue: "^2.6.9"

Answer (score 4):

For vue 3, refs are deprecated. I found that a workaround this is by using element id.  You can use

```
<v-file-input
  id="fileUpload"
  accept=".pdf"
  hide-input
  prepend-icon=""
/>
<div>
  <v-btn @click="getFile">
    UPLOAD
  </v-btn>
</div>
```

then on your event function for your button you can use,

```
const getFile = function () {
  let fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload')
  if (fileUpload != null) {
    fileUpload.click()
  }
}
```

Comment: AFIK, `refs are not deprecated` in vue3 but it now returns a proxy instead of a reference to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE February 2022**

*The best solution for any version is adding a id to the input or v-file-input then hide the input, in case you use v-file-input remove the icon by passing prepend-icon="" and hide-input .*

```
<v-btn @click="document.getElementById('uploader').click()">
   Upload Button text here
   <v-file-input hide-input prepend-icon="" id="uploader"></v-file-input>
</v-btn>
```

*in case you get this error:*

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementById')

*just put document in data*

```
data: () => ({
    document,
    other: true
})
```

Comment: Fantastic. This worked for me, after so many failed attempts of using refs.

Answer (score -1):

```
<v-file-input ref="fileInput"/>

<v-btn @click="open">
  UPLOAD
</v-btn>

open(){
  this.$refs.fileInput.$refs.input.click()
}
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.