# How to open component v-file-input, when it is hidden?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to use component `v-file-input` for upload file. But this component not suitable for design.

I try do next. I made this component  whole hidden `<v-file-input hide-input prepend-icon=""></v-file-input>`. Also I made a button, design I need. But I can  not start component `v-file-input` in method by click the button.

How can I start this component in the method?

Comment: This answer to a related question helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030356/v-file-input-click-is-not-a-function#comment111461866_63030356

Answer (score 3):

You can try to make label as button, and call method on label click:

```css
.upload {
  margin: 2em;
}
#btn {
  border: 2px solid #3457D5;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn:hover {
  background: #3457D5;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload">
  <input id="up" type="file" style="display: none" />
  <label id="btn" for="up">Upload</label>
</div>
```

Comment: These standard input is not suitable for me. I have to use a component vuetify `v-file-input`, which is hidden. Accordingly, I have to start it in the other method by click. Or maybe I did not understand something in your answer.

Comment: Sorry mate, my bad, i didn't understand your question, didn't know that `v-file-input` has something special comparing with default file input, i will remove my terrible answer, cheers :)